# Why I have an error, but not an exception?

Tags: java, cloneable

[documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html)

> Invoking Object's clone method on an instance that does not implement
> the Cloneable interface results in the exception
> CloneNotSupportedException being thrown.

Why I have an error

> clone() has protected access in java.lang.Object

but not CloneNotSupportedException exception?

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test2 c1 = new Test2();
        Test2 c2 = (Test2) c1.clone(); // error: clone() has protected access in java.lang.Object
    }
}

class Test2
{

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the error is at compile time.

Exception are at runtime. The program didn't even compile, so you didn't reach runtime.